# how to fix list index out of range error in this case?

Tags: python-3.x, indexoutofrangeexception, crossword

crossword vertical solve function,
the program gives list index out of range in '`if crosswords[num]==None`' sratement

that statement is provided to eliminate such error

```
def find_word_vertical(crosswords,word):
    word_list=[i for i in word]
    l=len(word_list)
    index=[]
    for col in range(len(crosswords[0])):
        for row in range(len(crosswords)):
            if word_list[0]==crosswords[row][col]:
                num=row
                ok=True
                for ch in range(l):
                    if crosswords[num]==None:
                        break
                        ok=False
                    else:
                        if word_list[ch]==crosswords[num][col]:
                            num+=1
                        else:
                            ok=False
                if ok:
                    return [row,col]
    return None
```

i can't find the mistake because the program runs for some example test case but the error shows up at an unknown test case. the exact test case does not appear on the screen because of 'out of index' error.
Sample Question=`find_word_vertical([['s','d','o','g'],['c','u','c','m'],['a','c','a','t'],['t','e','t','k']],'cat')`

Comment: How are we supposed to debug this without knowing what case causes the error? Please figure that out first (e.g. maybe print each test case before calling `find_word_vertical`) then come back and [edit] the question. Also include the call to `find_word_vertical`.

Comment: the test case changes if the is program is slightly changed. Is there another way?

Comment: To be clear, the code looks like it should work. I mean it's a bit hard to follow and it's not a [mcve], but `crosswords[row]` where `row` is in `range(len(crosswords))` should be guaranteed to exist.

Comment: Maybe you could put `print(crosswords, word)` as the first line in `find_word_vertical`?

Comment: doing that it prints the first test case and an 'not correct answer'. but the code works for that test case. (output for first test case [1,0]

Answer (score 0):

```
if crosswords[num]==None:
    break
    k=False
```

this statement was wrong and the correct statement is:

```
if num>=len(crosswords):
    k=False
    break
```

if element doesn't exist in list it does not return None but rather an error.